# How do you count cells with a certain partial string?

Tags: string, google-sheets, count, wildcard, google-sheets-formula

I have cells with dates that are formatted in different ways (and too messy to re-format, also lots of data) but if I want to count how many dates are in October, for example, I was hoping to do a `COUNTIF()` or `COUNTA(FILTER())` but I'm not sure how to search the cell for the partial string `10/` (this is the only unique combination of characters that I can think of that would ID only the correct month).

Answer (score 29):

You can use * wild character, the wild character before the value means anything ending with and at the end means anything starting with...

`=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*10/*")` - Has the text 10/ anywhere in the cell

`=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*"&B1&"*")` - Cell B1 has the finding text

`=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"10/*")` - Has the text 10/ at start

`=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*10/")` - Has the text 10/ at end

Comment: Brilliant answer, and avoids using functions to search the text unnecessarily.

Comment: Be careful. If you're using wildcards at the beginning, and the text to be searched only appears at the beginning, it won't be matched. In other words, if you use `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"*10/")` and the text to be searched is `10/SOMETHINGELSE`, it won't be matched.